# json различие '{' от '['

Tags: json

Когда нужно использовать [, А когда { ?

Пример кода:

```
{
    "text1": "text",
    "text2": {
        "text3" "text4"
    }
}
```

Можно так

А можно так:

```
{
    "text1": "text2",
    "text3": [
        {
            "text4": "text5"
        }
    ]
}
```

Разница не много не понятна.
Да и к тому же можно `{"1":{}}`

Comment: `{}` - словарь. `[]` - массив (список)

Comment: `JSON` == `JavaScript Object Notation`, поэтому за ответом и обращайтесь к `JS`. Как уже сказали выше, `{}` - объект (словарь), `[]` - массив.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Странный вопрос, потому что обычно изучают объекты, массивы, потом только доходят до JSON. У вас получилось наоборот.

Полезно понимать, что JSON (JavaScript Object Notation) - всего лишь текстовое представление набора данных, состоящих из обычных объектов или массивов, или и того и другого.

Если в кратце, в `{фигурных}` скобках хранятся данные вида `"Ключ": "значение"`. По умному это называется "Ассоциативный массив", в JS принято его называть просто "объект". Частый пример: Телефонная книжка, где перед каждым именем есть своё значение:

```js
let obj = {
  "John": "1111",
  "Tony": "2222",
  "Mary": "3333",
};

// Есть два способа "достать" значение из объекта. Через точку:
console.log( obj.John ); // 1111
// И через квадратные скобки и кавычки.
console.log( obj["John"] ); // 1111

// Если название ключа - просто строка без пробелов, используют запись через "точку".
```

Но часто бывает нужно делать объект с числовыми ключами, и что-то в нем перечислять. Можно было ровно также писать ключи из чисел, но придумали короткий способ, завернули его в `[квадратные]` скобки и назвали массивом (array), сверху добавили кучу полезных методов конкретно для массива:

```js
let obj = {
  "0": "John",
  "1": "Tony",
  "2": "Mary",
};

let array = ["John", "Tony", "Mary"];

console.log( obj[0] ); // John
console.log( array[0] ); // John
```

Но массивы и объекты могут быть вложены друг в друга:

```js
let obj = {
  "John": {
    "id": "0001",
    "interests": ["Music", "Painting"],
  },
  "Tony": {
    "id": "0002",
    "interests": [],
  },
};

console.log( obj.John.interests[0] ) // Music
```

Выбор структуры зависит от конкретной задачи.

Подробнее → https://learn.javascript.ru/ ( 4.1 - Объекты, 5.4 - Массивы, 5.12 - JSON )

P.s.

> Да и к тому же можно {"1":{}}

Управлять элементами массива сильно легче, благодаря встроенным методам. Поэтому это не одно и то же. Но даже если массив в дальнейшем будет использоваться исключительно чтобы получать значения по номеру - запись с квадратными скобками просто короче.

Comment: Спасибо, вы просто не поняли не много: я знаю php и json. Но не понимал зачем использовать [] если есть {}