# Как распарсить массив json

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

Есть массив:

```
{
  "title_ru": Мидуэй,
  "year": "2019",
  "genres": [
    {
      "id": 10752,
      "name": "военный"
    },
    {
      "id": 36,
      "name": "история"
    },
    {
      "id": 28,
      "name": "боевик"
    },
    {
      "id": 18,
      "name": "драма"
    }
  ]
}
```

Как мне вытащить имена из GENRES через JQUERY?
Не зннаю как выводить вложенные массивы

html

```
<div class="load">загрузить</div>
<div class="title"></div>
<div class="year"></div>
<div class="genre"></div>
```

js

```
$(".load").click(function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: "https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/522162?api_key=b6592428d620b6b47652d24b2242e898&language=ru-RU",
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (result) {
            var title_ru = result["title"],
            year = result["release_date"].substring(0, 4),
            genre = result["genres"];

            $('.title').text(title_ru);
            $('.year').text(year);
            $('.genre').text(genre)

        }
    });
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/dowjsz0L/

Comment: `$('.genre').text( result.genres.map( e => e.name ).join(", ") );` Array.map() → подменяет каждый элемент массива на что-то другое. В данном случае `{"id": 10752, "name": "военный"}` (e) заменяется на => `"военный"` (e.name). P.s. вместо `result["title"]` пишут `result.title` если это просто слово без пробелов и спец-символов.

Comment: @OPTIMUSPRIME все доходчиво и понятно, спасибо большое. А не подскажете еще, можно ли каждый жанр обернуть в ссылку, и адресом сделать id, например?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ну, jQuery нацелен на удобную работу с элементами страницы. Для таких задачек нужно изучать массивы и объекты в самом JS ( [json различие '{' от '['](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1052481/json-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%87%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%be%d1%82/1052491#1052491) ). В jQuery нет особых фишек для этого.

```js
let title_ru = "Мидуэй";
let year = 2019;
let genres = [
  {"id": 10752, "name": "военный"},
  {"id": 36, "name": "история"},
  {"id": 28,"name": "боевик"},
  {"id": 18,"name": "драма"}
];

/**************/

$('.title').text( title_ru );
$('.year').text( year );

let links = createLinks( genres ).join(", ");
$('.genre').html( links );

function createLinks(genres){
  return genres.map( item => {
    return `<a href="http://example.com?bubu=${ item.id }">${ item.name }</a>`;
    
    // Берет каждый объект из genres и подменяет его на созданную строку.
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="title"></div>
<div class="year"></div>
<div class="genre"></div>
```

P.s. знак `$` в строке не имеет отношения к jQ. Это встроенная фишка для строк с обратными кавычками. По-умному называется "интерполяция".

P.P.s. `item => item.id` то же самое, что `function (item) { return item.id }`, называется "стрелочная функция"